# Calculation with seconds vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column in excel that stores the difference between and end date and start date in seconds.

```
Time window seconds
2580 (0:43)
16200
```

I would like to sum these seconds and store this information in an array. This array should then contain the totalnumber of seconds. However if I specify this array as:

```
Dim totalnumber(7) as Date
```

I get weird values in Date format, instead of seconds. The next step is to do a simple calculation with each number stored in the array. How should I define this array so that it contains seconds and that I can do a calculation with it?

Comment: Lookup Date in Help: "_values to the left of the decimal represent date information while values to the right of the decimal represent time. Midnight is 0 and midday is 0.5. Negative whole numbers represent dates before 30 December 1899._" This tells you how to manipulate dates, if the columns contain seconds as Dates and are not integer numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a whole number representing the number of seconds, I would use an array of Long.

```
Dim seconds(7) as Long
```

**PROTIP**: You can use the `DateAdd` and `DateDiff` functions to calculate Dates and portions of Dates with and from whole numbers. E.g.

```
Dim lSeconds as Long
lSeconds = DateDiff("s", date1, date2)

Dim dtNew as Date
dtNew = DateAdd("s", lSeconds, date1)
```

See here:

[DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx)

[DateAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcxe65wz(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate the difference between two days, the Date format gives you a value that is expressed in days. Digits after the decimal point give you the hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, etc. For example, the Date value 2.5 would represent 2 days, 12 hours (12 hours = 0.5 days).

To convert a Date value to seconds, multiply by 86,400 (86,400 seconds in a day).